# How does a polar triangle characterize/ define a hyperbolic ellipse?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I am reading a paper stating the following:

> "In the Cayley-Klein model, hyperbolic ellipses are conics that lie in
>   the interior of K. The ellipse center is the unique vertex c of the
>   common polar triangle P of C and K. It is indeed a center in
>   elementary sense, as it halves the (hyperbolic) distance between the
>   ellipse points on any line incident with c. The axes of C are the two
>   sides of P through c. Degenerate pole triangles characterize the
>   circles among the ellipses. Their center is still well-defined but the
>   axes are undetermined so that any line through c can be addressed as
>   axis. Figure 2 below displays a hyperbolic ellipse, its center and
>   axes in the Cayley-Klein model."

[image]

**QUESTION:
Could anybody explain how to get the aforementioned "common polar triangle P of C and K" (or how to obtain the hyperbolic ellipse C based on the polar triangle, for that matter)? 
A step by step construction and/ or general explanation would be super helpful!**

Nota Bene: I looked up the definition for "polar triangle", but it didn't make sense in the context of hyperbolic ellipses. 
According to Wikipedia: *The polar triangle associated with a triangle ABC is defined as follows. Consider the great circle that contains the side BC. This great circle is defined by the intersection of a diametral plane with the surface. Draw the normal to that plane at the centre: it intersects the surface at two points and the point that is on the same side of the plane as A is (conventionally) termed the pole of A and it is denoted by A'. The points B' and C' are defined similarly.*